# Combining PDO and DAO pattern

Tags: php, pdo, dao

How could PHP's PDO feature and the [DAO pattern](http://www.odi.ch/prog/design/php/guide.php) be mixed? Should I have an abstract class that initializes a connection to the database? Can PDO be considered as equivalent to Java's JDBC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How could PHP's PDO feature and the DAO pattern be mixed?

Just use pdo to make queries into your dao object.

```
class PersonDAO {

   function get($id) {
     //> EXECUTE HERE PDO
   }

}
```

Also PDO already abstracts the connection, so you don't need an abstract class for connection.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, PDO is pretty much the "equivalent" of JDBC but in PHP.

You should pass an instance of PDO in the constructor of your domain objects (dependency injection):

```
abstract class Object {
    protected $_pdo;

    protected $_target;

    public function __construct(PDO $pdo) {
        $this->_pdo = $pdo;
    }

    public function load($id) {
        // $this->_pdo->something()
    }

    public function save() {
        // $this->_pdo->something()
    }

    public function delete() {
        // $this->_pdo->something()
    }
}

class User extends Object {
    protected $_target = 'user_table';

    public $name;
}
```

Then:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=foobar');
$user = new User($pdo);
$user->name = 'netcoder';
$user->save();
```

You could also add a static method in `Object` to specify a default instance:

```
class Object {
    // ...

    static protected $_defaultPDO;

    static public function setDefaultPDO(PDO $pdo) {
        self::$_defaultPDO = $pdo;
    }

    public function __construct(PDO $pdo = null) {
        if (!isset($pdo)) $pdo = self::$_defaultPDO;
        if (!isset($pdo))
            throw new DomainException('No default PDO object defined');

        $this->_pdo = $pdo;
    }
}

Object::setDefaultPDO(new PDO('mysql:dbname=foobar'));
$user = new User;
$user->name = 'James P.';
$user->save();
```

Comment: What would you do in the case lets say you need to join a user to an additional table to get more info, would you create a proxy class such as Users, that had methods to run more complex queries, or i guess even simpler what if you wanted to pull back all users, not just one?

Comment: @NateGates Applying the DAO pattern you could have a corresponding class for User and have methods such as `getAllUsers`, `getUsersByLoginDate` or `getUsersByIP`.